# Why my Radio buttons are checked automatically? How can I send only one by default in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ng-bootstrap

***The problem I have now is that I have two `radio-button`s, the thing I want is that when you click `admin` radio button you can see one form and when you click the `user` radio button you can see another form. Until now both are checked and I don't know why, only want one to be checked by default and that one will show one form at a time***

- Below I will post the code of the radios and the picture of them. I'm using `angular-material`.

***Radio button's html***

```html
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" class="center">
    <mat-radio-button  (click)="radio_btn=true" >Admin</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button (click)="radio_btn=false">User</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
  <div class="ng-container ">
        <div class="row justify-content-center" *ngIf="radio_btn==true">
        <form class="example-form " [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="send(signupForm)">
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput formControlName="email" placeholder="User" type="email">
          </mat-form-field><br>
          <div *ngIf="signupForm.get('email').hasError('email') && signupForm.get('email').touched">Introduce an email</div><br>
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
          </mat-form-field><br>
          <div *ngIf="signupForm.get('password').hasError('password') && signupForm.get('password').touched">Introduce the correctly password</div><br>
          <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="signupForm.invalid" class="colour_button " type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

***TS file of the radio's***

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  radio_btn:boolean = true;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

***This is how they looks like***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your radio group:

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="radio_btn”
```

Then have

```
<mat-radio-button [value]=“true“
```

And

```
    <mat-radio-button [value]=“false”
```

Also remove the (click) handlers from the radio buttons.

To change the radio_btn value.

See [Material radio example html](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples).

Comment: When i put the `[(ngModel)]="radio_btn”` says `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-radio-group'`

Comment: You likely need to import FormsModule or MatRadioModule to your app or component module. Have a search on those to check if that is the issue.

Comment: Sorry i didn't answer, i found out another way to solve it, i will put how i did it. But your way also works because i tried too